# Mysql Crosstab validating existence

Tags: mysql, sql, reporting

Iam new in stackoverflow, i have some issues trying to do the subj. report.

Table Example

```
Group  Client   Atribute
Group1 Client1  Atribute1
Group1 Client1  Atribute1
Group1 Client2  Atribute2
Group2 Client3  Atribute1
Group3 Client4  Atribute2
Group3 Client5  Atribute2
Group3 Client5  Atribute2
Group3 Client6  Atribute3
```

Note: The client and Group column will be repetead as this example.

Needed Report

```
Group  Client Atribute1 Atribute2 Atribute3 
Group1 Client1  Yes         no       no 
Group1 Client2  no          yes      no 
Group2 Client3  yes         no       no 
Group3 Client4  no          yes      no 
Group3 Client5  no          yes      no 
Group3 Client6  no          no       yes
```

The major complication is that we need to validate customer by customer if haver or have not the diferent atributes.

I am stuck in the beginning, I thought something like this:

```
SELECT
 group,
 client,
 CASE WHEN EXISTS
 (SELECT client FROM table
  WHERE client IN ( SELECT client FROM table
  WHERE Atribute = 3 ) -- The problem is that since there is an attribute for one of the    clients the subquery result true and will go to the "THEN" dor all the clients.
 ) THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS Atribute3,
FROM
 table
GROUP BY group, client
```

Any help will be appreciated. Excuse my English! Best reggards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this with dynamic SQL

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
         CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN atribute = ''',
                atribute,
                ''' THEN ''yes'' ELSE ''no'' END) ',
                atribute))
  INTO @sql
  FROM table1;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT `group`, client, ', @sql, ' 
                   FROM table1 
                   GROUP BY `group`, client');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Output:

```
|  GROUP |  CLIENT | ATRIBUTE1 | ATRIBUTE2 | ATRIBUTE3 |
|--------|---------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| Group1 | Client1 |       yes |        no |        no |
| Group1 | Client2 |        no |       yes |        no |
| Group2 | Client3 |       yes |        no |        no |
| Group3 | Client4 |        no |       yes |        no |
| Group3 | Client5 |        no |       yes |        no |
| Group3 | Client6 |        no |        no |       yes |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9be78/6)** demo

To simplify things on the calling end you can wrap it into a stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_report()
BEGIN
  SET @sql = NULL;

  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
           CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN atribute = ''',
                  atribute,
                  ''' THEN ''yes'' ELSE ''no'' END) ',
                  atribute))
    INTO @sql
    FROM table1;

  SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT `group`, client, ', @sql, ' 
                     FROM table1 
                     GROUP BY `group`, client');

  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And then use it like

```
CALL sp_report();
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17310/1)** demo